# Не получается ввести несколько значений

Tags: c#, суммирование

Компилятор выкидывает необработанное исключение после ввода любого символа, что не правильно?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace metanit_47
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите несколько чисел (нажмите \"z\" для завершения):");
            int d;
            int sum = 0;
            char ch=' ';
            while(ch!='z')
            {
                d = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                sum += d;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма введенных чисел равна " + sum);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас условие выхода из цикла `ch!='z'`, но переменную `ch` вы нигде не изменяете, у вас получается бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про попытки распарсить в `int` любое введённое значение и бесконечный цикл из-за неизменяемого `ch` уже написали. Приведу пример реализации с использованием `int.TryParse` и учетом конца потока ввода как альтернативной причины завершения цикла:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите несколько чисел (нажмите \"z\" для завершения):");
var sum = 0;
var input = Console.ReadLine();
while (input != null && input != "z")
{
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
        sum += number;
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Сумма введенных чисел равна " + sum);
```

Comment: А зачем `input.Equals`? Это ж не Java.

Comment: @VladD так вот и бывает, когда пишешь параллельно на нескольких языках :) И если, например, с лямбдами IDE сразу подсказывает, что опять перепутал `=>` с `->`, то с `Equals` для `string` VS молчит. Спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 2):

Метод [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) преобразует строковое представление числа в целочисленное значение. В случае, если вы пытаетесь передать методу что-то отличное от [представления числа](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) то вы получите исключение `FormatException`, что и происходит в вашем случае.

Если вы хотите приводить строку к числу и вместо исключения получать `false` то воспользуйтесь [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Вам нужно переделать вашу программу таким образом, что сперва получать ввод с консоли, проверять полученное значение на `'z'`, а затем пытаться приводить к `int` иначе у вас получиться если не исключение, то бесконечный цикл.